# Bootstrap modal fails to load content

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have two tabs in a page, both tabs contain a modal class. Modal in the first tab works fine, i.e. it fades-in and loads the content.However, when I switch to the next tab it only fades-in and doesn't show the content when I used chrome debugger I found in the first tab  is comming while in second tab  is comming

```
<button  type="button"
    class="btn btn-info glyphicon glyphicon-plus"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myModal{{$parent.$parent.$index}}{{$index}}">
        Add URL
</button>

{{category.name}}{{$parent.$parent.$index}}{{$index}}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$parent.$parent.$index}}{{$index}}" role="dialog">
     {{$parent.$parent.$index}} -- {{$index}}
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content" >{{category.name}}
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <form>
                      <p>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control"
                           name="uri" placeholder="Add URL" ng-model="uri">
                      </p>
                   </form>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" ng-click="addCustom()"
                           class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-lg-2 col-md-offset-3 glyphicon glyphicon-ok"
                           data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
                   <button type="button"
                           class="btn btn-success btn-sm col-lg-2 col-md-offset-7 pull-centre glyphicon glyphicon-remove"
                           data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need to post some code if you want help

Comment: posted the code @cfly24

Comment: anything related to Tab-index @cfly24

Comment: anything related to Tab-Index @Fiido Fridauz

Comment: when I used chrome debugger I found in the first tab <div class="modal fade ng-binding in" id="myModal00" role="dialog" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;"> is comming while in second tab <div class="modal fade ng-binding " id="myModal00" role="dialog" > is comming @FiidoFirdauz

Comment: Please see my above comment @cfly24

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure whats going wrong. Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to show the issue